# Qt 5 + QMediaPlayer (Video Widget example) is unable to play Video file

Tags: qt, video, gstreamer, qt5, qtgstreamer

I am trying Qt 5 with videowidget example in which QMediaplayer is used to play video file.
It gives me error like 
***Error: "GStreamer encountered a general stream error."***

when i play any mp4 file in it. It is not able to play a single file.

But on having same environment if i use old SDK Qt 4.8.2 and use Phonon and play same file then its fine. Its working.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening with new SDK QT 5.1.1?

Regards,
Keyur

Answer (score 0):

Do you have all GStreamer 0.10 plugins installed on your machine? A codec might be missing. With gst-plugins-good, gst-plugins-ugly, gst-plugins-bad and gst-plugins-ffmpeg installed, you should be able to play pretty much any format.

Answer (score 0):

Although Phonon can use GStreamer as a backend, QtMultimedia doesn't use Phonon. It seems like you're [not the only one who is having it](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/29847).

There are bug reports of videos not playing like [this one](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTMOBILITY-994), and Qt developers say the most common case is missing codecs. Please check whether you're not missing any gstreamer codec.