# Qmultimedia and gstreamer error on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, gstreamer, qtmultimedia

I can't read any video files with Qt. I have tried the Qt example and it still doesn't work. I have installed every packages needed to read video files with GStreamer.

In the QtCreator debug window, I have this message :

```
error : GStreamer encountered a general stream error
```

I have searched for a long time but haven't found any solution... Does anyone have one?

[EDIT]
I could solve this problem using QGraphicVideoItem instead of QVideoWidget but now i have an other problem :

```
(camera_capture:7943): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'GstObject'

(camera_capture:7943): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(camera_capture:7943): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_type > 0' failed

(camera_capture:7943): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(camera_capture:7943): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_class_set_details_simple: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT_CLASS (klass)' failed

(camera_capture:7943): GStreamer-WARNING **: static caps 0x7f22942a1fb0 string is NULL

(camera_capture:7943): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_mini_object_unref: assertion 'mini_object != NULL' failed

(camera_capture:7943): GStreamer-WARNING **: static caps 0x7f22942a2030 string is NULL

(camera_capture:7943): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_mini_object_unref: assertion 'mini_object != NULL' failed

(camera_capture:7943): GStreamer-WARNING **: static caps 0x7f22942a1fb0 string is NULL

(camera_capture:7943): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_mini_object_unref: assertion 'mini_object != NULL' failed
```

Thanks

PS: I'm sorry for my approximate english...

Comment: does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19006138/qt-5-qmediaplayer-video-widget-example-is-unable-to-play-video-file help?

Comment: Spelling and grammar corrections

Comment: new edition: new error